# Manage by storeview

Tags: magento-1.7, store-view

possible for my customers add groups where first all users looks my site always with prices and etc... and goups where only register (password access) can look site with other prices and discount (another store view will be great), i use magento 1.7.0.2, if this possible let me know
Thanks for all